# facing issue when open view in new tab jquery isn't loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm facing an issue with my MVC application i have some **jquery function** written on my Layout page and i call these function from different views, but on a specific VIEW when i open this view by clicking from menu it will work fine but when **I open the view in new tab from menu by right click on it so jquery isn't loaded**. Its happening only in 1 View of my application i have several views and all are working fine.
any leads why this happen ?

In my Layout page **Function activateNav** is written and its working properly when view is open from menu by just single click, but when I'm trying to open it in new tab by right clicking the layout page Function (activateNav) isn't accessible however same scenario is working from different views
Thanks in advance.
script at my view :

```
<script type="text/javascript" async>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).on('load', function () {*/
            jQuery('.actMenu').removeClass("actSubMenu");
            $("#subIn").parent().addClass("actSubMenu");
            activateNav('#processT', '#subIn');
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: It's hard for us to know what's wrong with your code if you don't add your code. pleas add your code. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Bjop updated please have a look.!

Comment: Is there more code to it? it sounds like jquery isn't loaded or the new page expects an argument. If you get a error message pls add it to.

Comment: @Bjop but same script is executed on the other views however opened it from menu by or open it in new tab, this issue occur in specific view only when i opened this view in new tab .

Comment: I think the problem is not in the js code but in the code of the view. It might be the issue: jquery is not loaded on that specific view.

Comment: @Bjop  thanks for your reply, but 
I'm saying view is loaded properly but whenever Im trying to open it in new tab by right click on it in menu so my Layout page function  is not accessible from my view only when i open it in new tab .clear ?